# Non-splitting extensions of groups with trivial center

Tags: group-theory, group-extensions

In my question I will use the notation of the [lecture notes](https://www.iazd.uni-hannover.de/fileadmin/iazd/sambale/teach/cgt.pdf) of my commutative group theory lecture (they are in German).

In the section about group extensions I am at the point of an extension of a nonabelian group $N$ with any group $H$. With the definition of matchings at 4.25 and 4.27 we get that the number of equivilance classes of parameter systems of $N$ with $H$ with some matching $w$ equal the number of equivilance classes of parameter systems of $Z:=Z(N)$ with $H$ with automorphism system $w_Z$.

Now in 4.28(i) we deduce that with $Z=1$ for every matching there is exactly one equivalence class of parameter systems that has this matching. And now I cannot figure out, why in 4.28(ii) we need another assumption for $N$ (namely $Aut(N)$ being a semidirect product of $Inn(N)$ and $Aut(N)/Inn(N)$) to deduce that every extension of $N$ splits. For any parameter system $(a,k)$ the function

$$w_a:H \to Out(N),x \mapsto a_xInn(N)$$

is a homomorphism and thus a matching for $a,k$. Thus, with (i), there is only one equivalence class of parameter systems with $a$ as automorphism system. Thus $(a,k)$ should be in the same equivalence class as $(a,1)$ as for any automorphism system $b$ the parameter system $(b,1)$ exists. Then however $a$ is an homomorphism and the chosen extension is equivalent (and thus isomorphic) to the semidirect product of $N$ and $H$.

This all leads to my question of: At what point did I mess up with my conclusions and why do we need to be able to lift matchings to automorphism systems? For the latter I understood that the lifting guarantees that $Par(w)$ is not empty, but I do not understand why that matters here.

In that context even an example of a non-splitting extension of a group with trivial center with any other group would really help me (I am not very good with central products, but there got to be a good example to find using those). Maybe with that I can find where I am wrong myself.

Thank you in advance for any help, I hope this question is reasonably put.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: I can't answer your question about where you messed up, but if $Z(N)=1$ and ${\rm Inn}(N)$ has no complement in ${\rm Aut}(N)$ then, since $N$ is naturally isomorphic to ${\rm Inn}(N)$, ${\rm Aut}(N)$ is itself a non-splitting extension of $N$ by ${\rm Aut}(N)/{\rm Inn}(N)$. So the extra assumption is certainly necessary. An non-splitting example is $N = A_6$, where ${\rm Aut}(N)/{\rm Inn}(N) \cong C_2 \times C_2$.

Comment: [This post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/293436) should be helpful for examples. Note that extraspecial $2$-groups are central products.

Comment: Thank you very much for the responses, it did help me out a lot and will help me to improve any following question I might ask as well. It turns out that for an arbitrary $N$ and $H$ with parameter system $(\alpha,\kappa)$ the parameter system $(\alpha,1)$ does not have to exist. For any such $N$ fullfilling the assumpion however it does and thus the splitting of the one possible extension follows.